# R purrr function: Sensitivity with multiple parameters

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have been working on this problem and can't seem to figure it out.

I have a dataset show below in which I want to run a cashflow sensitivity to price.  The dataset will have appended rows, but the problem I am running into is using the different prices with the unique labor cost and matching them to their unique stations.

```
a <- data.frame(Name = "station1", units_sold = seq(2000, 3000, by = 2))
b <- data.frame(Name = "station2", units_sold = seq(1000, 2000, by = 2))

monthly_sales <- rbind(a, b)

price_1 <- c(2,3,4,5,6) #price for station_1
price_2 <- c(3,4,5,6,7) #price for station_2

labor1 <- c(1000) #labor for station_1
labor2 <- c(2000) #labor for station_2
```

I am using the code below and I am not able to apply `price_1` and `labor_1` to `station_1`, and then `price_2` and `labor_2` to `station_2` for my sensitivity.

How do I setup my `cf_model` function or the `map` function to match the unique labor and price parameters?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
cf_model <- function(x)
{
  data.frame(Scenario = (monthly_sales$units_sold * price_1[x]))
}
sensitivity_model <- data.frame(map(1:5, cf_model))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to figure out what you want to do exactly.
Do you want to find out what net revenue you will have if you have different assumptions about items sold, price per item and (total) labor costs?

If this is so I think the quickest way would look like e.g.

```
    scenario_station_1 <- data.frame(a$units_sold %*% t(price_1) - labor1)
    names(scenario_station_1)<-as.character(price_1)
```

Comment: I am sorry I was unclear, but your assessment is correct. Thank you for your response.  I import thing I failed to mention is that the list of units will be dynamic, sometimes it will be just 1 unit and other times it could be 5 units all with unique prices and labor cost.  How can you model it with making it a static naming convention e.g. price_1?

Comment: OK, let's not expand the topic for too long as it seems we do not have an R issue here but more a discussion of how you should organize your data.
You seem to be interested in defining your input data as follows:
`unit.type    price  labor.cost
car          10000  3000
bicycle      1000   600
skateboard   100    40`
Key point is that you add another dimension to your scenario as you must define "items X produced".  I suggest you plan the architecture of your "scenarios" on a sheet of paper or in Excel, then open up another thread if there should be specific R questions :-)

Comment: Thank you for your advice and I will come at this from a different direction....thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is to use `map` with 2 parameters, which would be `map2`.

In this case your function `cf_model` would be a function which takes in two parameters, being the parameter for `price_1` and `price_2`; you should never really need to index it.

In this example it would be:

```
cf_model <- function(price_1, price_2){
  data.frame(Scenario = (a$units_sold*price_1 + b$units_sold*price_2))
}
sensitivity_model <- data.frame(map2(price_1, price_2, cf_model))

head(sensitivity_model)
```

Notice I did not use your table `monthly_sales`. If I was to use it it would be:

```
monthly_sales <- data.frame(station1=a$units_sold, 
                            station2=b$units_sold)
sensitivity_model <- data.frame(map2(price_1, price_2, 
                       ~ list(Sensitivity=.x*monthly_sales$station1 + .y*monthly_sales$station2)))
```

In both cases it will have the same output:

```
> head(sensitivity_model)
  Scenario Scenario.1 Scenario.2 Scenario.3 Scenario.4
1     7000      10000      13000      16000      19000
2     7010      10014      13018      16022      19026
3     7020      10028      13036      16044      19052
4     7030      10042      13054      16066      19078
5     7040      10056      13072      16088      19104
6     7050      10070      13090      16110      19130
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was very helpful.  To add another wrinkle to my problem, I don't always have the same number of station or labor costs.  Some months I might need to run a sensitivity on 2 stations with unique labor cost and different prices and some months I might have 5.  Do you think this might be best to handle with a for loop?

Comment: Might be easier if you raise another question with sample input outputs of what you're after